Xinclude syntax
I'm getting this error in oXygen XMl Editor 26.01
Include operation failed, reverting to fallback. Resource error reading file as XML (href='changelog.xsl'). Reason: InvalidShortHandPointer: The NCName of the ShortHand Pointer 'xpath((//p)[1]/@id)' is invalid.

for this expression
<xi:include href="changelog.xsl" xpointer="(//p)[1]/@id"/>

How could it be rewritten?
I'm using it in the context of XSLT 4.0 file.

Do you want to include an attribute node with XInclude? I don't think that is supported at all. As for the xpointer, it might be better asking the oXygen support what parts they support or don't support.
